# How to open terminal. gconftool not found

Tags: command-line, sound, gconf

I'm trying to re-set the defaults for audio playback, and I read in a similar post to enter `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal/` into terminal.  "Sorry, no results."  The only results I get in the terminal are for things like Audacity.  No commands have produced any results.

I need to  find out how to edit 'profile' in the terminal, I think (newbie think).

Comment: Are you talking about trying to run gconftool from the dash?  If so then you need to search for "Terminal", launch it, and then run the gsettings command.

Comment: I couldn't understand very well. What OS do you have? *(Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04, etc.)* Your problem is that you can't open the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You're typing those commands into the dash, I think (the thing that pops up when you hit the windows key), not a terminal.

To open up a terminal, open the dash (press the windows key) and type `terminal`, and the first thing to pop up should be the terminal (you'll need to click on it). Or, you can press `ctrl+alt+t`.

To paste into a terminal, you need to use `ctrl+shift+v`. You'll need to press enter after pasting the command in.

I can't vouch for that particular command, though, nor am I sure exactly what you want to do. Do you want to set Rhythmbox as your default player of music? That can be set in System Settings, under Details. Please clarify your question, with a link to where you got that command from.

Comment: Sorry, the gconftool was in a thread somewhere.  Thanks, evilsoup, I got it open.  I also was able to delete/reinstall audacity, but it is not recording.  Error message: Check input device settings and project sample rate.  Output and mic are set at "Intel ICH6 (hw:0,0)".   I don't really use the mic, except for Skype, but I could use it in the future for recording.  I have and IBM Thinkpad, 32kbs, I386.  I have Ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to learn about Settings.  I don't understand Skip. I'm used to Total Recorder, a great program, on Windows XP.  Thanks again for your help, all.